# What is the Dharma of women of all varnas?

Tags: dharma, varna

We know that Dharma is different for all men of different varnas. Is there Dharma defined for women of different varnas? I have not found it in any scripture so far. Dharma of all women seems to be similar - household duties. How can one distinguish the dharma of women of different varnas?